# October CMS How to Change Path of File Upload?

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm using October CMS.

I made a simple front-end File Upload Plugin. I have a Model and Component.

[image: upload form]

**In Model Uploader.php I use**

```
public $attachOne = [
    'videofile' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

**And in the Component**

```
public function onUpload(){
    $uploader = new Uploader();
    $uploader->videofile = Input::file('videofile');
    $uploader->save();
    Flash::success('File Uploaded');
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

**By default, Uploads go to**

```
/storage/app/uploads/public/random-dir/random-name.mp4
```

The CMS is giving the files a random directory and name.

**But backend *Media* Uploads go to**

```
/storage/app/media/filename.mp4
```

The File name is preserved.

How do I make the files upload to /media instead of /uploads/public?

Or is it possible to define a folder and filename instead of random in /uploads/public?

Comment: Does $uploader->save() is being inherited or it's a function you've wrote?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I followed a guide. I didn't write the save function. I think it's being inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the file before attaching it to the Uploader model:

```
Input::file('videofile')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

You can get the original filename like this

```
$name = Input::file('videofile')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for moving the file. When I use $uploader->videofile = (your move code), and save(), the File Upload Data is empty in the database, when before it had details and path link. Would you know how to save the new location to the database? https://i.imgur.com/Pz9pIJu.png

Comment: Did you save the model after moving the file?

Comment: I saved after moving. If not moving the file (default), the system_files database table is updated. If moving file, it is not updated. I view the table info through columns.yaml. Here's a screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/A0udWWB.jpg

Comment: You have to save the File model, not the uploader.
In your case the `$uploader->videofile`

Comment: How do I save the file model? I tried this but I can't access it from my Uploader class. https://i.imgur.com/JuhJxaQ.png

Comment: I did use System\Models\File and $file = new File(); It now talks to the database but can't write to the tables. Unknown column error. But it writes to the tables if you don't move the file.